# How can I give my browser localhost:80/foo.js when it asks for www.productionsite.com/foo.js?

Tags: browser, proxy

I'm doing work on "foo.js", a previous version of which is currently deployed on "www.productionsite.com". I'd like to see how the new version of foo.js behaves on the production version of productionsite.com before I actually deploy it.

www.productionsite.com loads the script from http://www.productionsite.com/js/somescript.js I'd like to find a way to have my browser load http://localhost:80/js/somescript.js instead

I've worked out a way to do this using apache and mod_proxy:

1. In /etc/hosts, re-route local.productionsite.com to localhost:80 (apache)
   Using mod_proxy, re-route all requests for local.productionsite.com/* to  www.productionsite.com/*
2. Make exceptions in the proxy setup for any assets I want to load locally. i.e.

This gets the job done, but is pretty cumbersome. What a want is a tool (presumably a proxy I'd point my browser to) which I can easily configure to replace specific assets, like:

> http://www.productionsite.com/js/somescript.js = http://localhost:80/js/somescript.js

or even

> http://www.productionsite.com/js/somescript.js = http://dev.productionsite.com/js/somescript.js

Is there any easier way to do this than what I'm currently doing? I'd prefer a mac os solution, but can use windows too.

Comment: what server side language are you using?

Comment: @SLaks I'm using a mac, but can use a pc if there's a good tool available.

Comment: @Abe Petrillo The server-side language is irrelevant. This question is entirely about client-side techniques.

Comment: I suspect that Fiddler can do this.

Comment: @morgancodes I was merely providing an alternative... he could have a conditional statement to include localost/js instead of /js...

Answer (score 0):

I believe that if you set your hosts file to refer back to 127.0.0.1 that should do what you want it to.

`C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`

or on unix (not sure about mac)

`/etc/hosts`

Add `www.productionsite.com` to your 127.0.0.1 entry:

`127.0.0.1       localhost <dns_name> www.productionsite.com`

Comment: This would work if I wanted the entirety of www.productionsite.com to be served from a local server. But I want all of www.productionsite.com to be served normally, EXCEPT for http://www.productionsite.com/js/somescript.js, which I want to point to a local version.